# "PROMOCODE1" coupon code is not valid

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

Hi all I will go straight to the point. I found out that when i create a shopping cart price rule in magento and added a promotion/coupon code as indicated above with all rules set correctly to have a discount works from the frontend as expected from customers checkout experience/process.

But when i try to create an order from the backend/admin and trying to apply the promocode1 coupon code to the order for a specific customer it shows it to be invalid. as indicated above.

My Version i am using currently is ver. 1.9.3.6

I hope someone can point me to the right direction or what i may be doing wrong or not doing.

snap shots below
[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please attach the cart rules for the promo code and the order your are trying this on.

Comment: I have included the snap shots to the problem now.

Comment: Have you confirm that, the user which is selected for order is belong to such group which you allowed while rule creation?

Comment: Yes user belongs to general and the group general is selected as part of the group to apply the price rule.

Comment: in your screenshots, uses per customer in coupon setting is 0 , try increasing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in magento as after several checks i realized that you have to select 'all store view' option during the creation of the price rule.

Even though you select the specific store view for the price rule, the coupon will not be applied to the order from the backend of magento without you selecting the 'all store view'.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but I am also getting the same error messages and i resolve my issue by removing the fields **reset_shipping: true** from sales.js file in js/mage/adminhtml from function applyCoupon. In myside whenever i am applying coupon code then my shipping price is going to reset so coupon code could not apply if shipping price is 0 ( my coupon code is to offer free shipping)